# ¿Cómo tener varios archivos en un objeto NodeJS y MongoDB?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿De qué manera podría introducir varias imágenes en un solo objeto? Quiero decir, supongamos que tengo en una aplicación un modelo creado de un proyecto, el cual tendrá diferentes propiedades, pero una de ellas es imágenes. En lo cual quiero que sea un array para poder introducir varias imágenes en el. Pero solo consigo hacer que suba de una en una, y que cuando subo otra nueva tape la anterior. Sinceramente no se ni por donde empezar. Gracias de antemano. Un saludo. Utilizo connect-multiparty para realizar la subida de archivos.

Archivo del modelo:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProyectSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    tecnologies: String,
    author: String,
    file: [String]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

Aquí está el código con la que lo subo:

```
function uploadImageFile(req, res){
    var idProyect = req.params.id;
    var file_name = 'No subido';

    if (req.files) {
        var file_path = req.files.file.path;
        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');
        var file_name = file_split[2];
        var ext_split = file_name.split('\.');
        var file_ext = ext_split[1];

        if (file_ext == 'png' || file_ext == 'jpg' || file_ext == 'gif') {
            Proyect.findByIdAndUpdate(idProyect, { file: file_name }, (err, updatedProyect) => {
                if (err) {return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en el servidor.'});}
                return res.status(200).send({proyect: updatedProyect});
            });
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({message: 'La extensión del archivo no es correcta.'});
        }
    }else{
        res.status(200).send({message: 'No has subido ningún archivo.'});
    }
}
```

Y aqui está la forma en la que instancio connect-multiparty, en el archivos de rutas de proyectos y lo coloco como middleware en la ruta:

```
multipart = require('connect-multiparty'),
md_upload = multipart({uploadDir: './uploads/images'});
```

ruta:

```
router.post('/uploadImageFile/:id', [md_auth.ensureAuth, md_upload], ImageController.uploadImageFile);
```

No sé si es posible subir los archivos a la vez que se crea el objeto de proyecto, y hasta el momento solo tengo idea de como subirlos una vez creado y editando el objeto.

Comment: Coloca el código fuente donde defines tu modelo, si usas mongoose o mongodb directamente y el código donde guardas el objeto con imagenes usando connect-multuparty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, según tu código, primero defines tu modelo indicando que se recibirá un array de objetos:

```
var ProyectSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    tecnologies: String,
    author: String,
    file: [{ img: String }] // file = array con objetos que tienen atributo img, puedes cambiar de nombre y agregar otros atributos como dateUpload o así
});
```

El atributo file equivale a poner:

```
file: [
  { img: 'img1' },
  { img: 'img2' },
  { img: 'img3' },
  { img: 'img4' },
  { img: 'imgN' }
]
```

Con esto ya le dijiste a mongoose que ese atributo tendrá un arreglo con objetos y que cada objeto tendrá un atributo llamado img que es donde se guardará la imagen, sea encodeada o su ruta.

¿Cómo agrego imágenes?

De tu ejemplo, coloco la parte más importante:

```
Proyect.findByIdAndUpdate(idProyect, { $push: {file: file_name} }, (err, updatedProyect) => {
    if (err) {return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en el servidor.'});}
    return res.status(200).send({proyect: updatedProyect});
});
```

Revisa la documentación de [push de mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.push) y de [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) prácticamente es parecido al push de javascript.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la atención prestada, me ayuda bastante. Andaba un poco desorientado y pensaba que  sería un poco más de locura, pero no contaba con la variable $push. Echaré un vistazo con más profundidad respecto a ello. Gracias !!!

Comment: Por nada, te sugiero primero le des un vistazo, si puedes hacerlo en base a la documentación mejorarás más, pero si se te dificulta puedo poner un ejemplo, pero te repito, si lo haces por tu cuenta siguiendo la doc, además de aprender a usar $push también estás forjando tu capacidad de aprender de manera "autodidacta" por así decirlo

Answer (score 0):

conseguí hacerlo de forma correcta, pero ha surgido una nueva duda, y el caso es que el frontend lo voy a desarrollar en Angular 2. Si en un modelo de nodeJs utilizo esto:

```
file: [{ img: String }]
```

como propiedad. ¿De que manera lo represento en el modelo de Angular? es decir, cuando hago las clases ¿Como lo tengo que hacer? Aquí si que no se donde acudir para recoger información sobre esto exactamente.